# Was Novak an Omnicorp shill?

Tags: robocop, robocop-2014

Was Pat Novak (of 'The Novak Report') an Omnicorp [shill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill) or was he just really, *really* keen on robotic law enforcement?

With the way he was biased for Omnicorp (e.g. OCP CEO warmly greeted back to his show) and against Senator Dreyfus (cut off in mid sentence, when he tries to counter a claim) I found it hard to believe he did not have a pecuniary interest in the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clear implication is that he **is** a shill or, at the very least benefiting in some way from his support of Raymond Sellars and his plans to import robots in the mainland US.

In an interview with [plucky girl reporter](http://proto.mtv.ca/omnicorp-and-the-novak-element-bring-you-the-introduction-of-robocop/) Maura Grierson (Kelly Perkins) we learn that the "Novak Report" has some sort of *inappropriate relationship* with Omnicorp:

> **What should RoboCop fans look forward to in the upcoming RoboCop?**
>
> The media aspect is really cool in the film. We have the power to sway
>   the public’s opinion of what is going on, especially Samuel L.
>   Jackson, he plays that character where you know what he’s saying,
>   millions and millions of people will believe and will stand behind.
>   **We are walking the line of influencing the country and sleeping with the enemy and that’s all I will say.**

For the record, the [www.NovakElement.com](http://www.NovakElement.com) website re-directs automatically to [Omnicorp.com](http://www.Omnicorp.com)

Comment: I also thought it was supposed to be a satirical jab at Fox News and presenters like Bill O'Reily.

Comment: @Monty129 - Oh absolutely. Sam Jackson said that he played him as a mixture of Rush Limbaugh and Al Sharpton...http://www.zap2it.com/blogs/robocop_at_comic-con_2013_samuel_l_jacksons_pat_novak_asks_why_is_america_so_robophobic-2013-07

Comment: Quick note: Your 'plucky girl reporter link' is dead, sorry I'm too lazy to look up a replacement.